# Update Stored Procedure in ExtJS

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, extjs4

I wrote a stored procedure where it will show the output values in the extjs grid.

If I edit any values inside the table in extjs how to update the values automatically by using stored procedure. I need to update my table in the grid using the stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spcr_g_sample]
    @Form varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        m.form_code, m.element_name, m.element_type, m.text_code,
        m.is_search, m.search_seq, m.search_operator_list, m.is_grid,
        m.grid_seq, m.is_customise, m.element_seq,
        l.search_config, l.grid_config, l.element_config  
    FROM
        samp_form m 
    JOIN
        samp_form_temp l ON m.samp_form_id  = l.samp_form_id
    WHERE
        m.form_code = m.form_code
        AND m.form_code = @Form
END
```